# Importing text file data into rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a text file which contain rows in this format:

com1,System Access,MinimumPasswordAge,1 
com1,System Access,MaximumPasswordAge,42
com1,System Access,MinimumPasswordLength,7

I wish to import this data in 3 seperate rows in the following format:

"com1" in `ID` column, 
"System Access" in `Audit_Type` column, 
"MinimumPasswordAge" in `System_Setting` column, and 
"1" in `Actual_Value` column.

Im using MySQL Query Browser in Windows 7 SP1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create table to hold your data.
2. Create CSV file. Do not include field headers.
3. Open MySQL Query Browser and run SQL:

---

```
load data local infile 'fullpath.csv' into table tableName
fields terminated by ','
lines terminated by '\n'
(ID, Audit_Type, System_Setting, Actual_Value);
```

**Note:**
If you have generated the text file on a Windows system, you might have to use `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'` to read the file properly, because Windows programs typically use two characters as a line terminator.

---

**UPDATE 1**

As you can see, `3 out of 81` records are only inserted

com1,System Access,MinimumPasswordAge,1 
com2,System Access,MinimumPasswordAge,1 
com3,System Access,MinimumPasswordAge,1

others fail

com1,Event Audit,AuditSystemEvents,0  
com2,Kerberos Policy,MaxTicketAge,10  
com3,System Access,NewAdministratorNameAdministrator, 1

It's because you set the column `ID` as the primary key. `com1, com2, com3` already existed on the table. **Primary Key is**, *by definition*, **unique**. The best way to do to be able to insert all rows is by creating another column which whill be auto-incremented and set this as primary key.

```
Create Table system_settings
(
    RecordID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ID VARCHAR(30),
    Audit_Type VARCHAR(30), 
    System_Setting VARCHAR(30), 
    Actual_Value int,
    CONSTRAINT table_PK PRIMARY KEY (RecordID) 
)
```

Comment: I tried the following code:
load data local infile 'C:/Users/student/Downloads/SecAudit.txt' into table system_settings
fields terminated by ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
(ID, Audit_Type, System_Setting, Actual_Value);

But only 3 of the 81 rows are imported. Why is that so?

Comment: can you specify at least 2 rows in your question that were not inserted? maybe these have problems with their formats because 3 out of 81 rows have been inserted.

Comment: Only "com1,System Access,MinimumPasswordAge,1"; "com2,System Access,MinimumPasswordAge,1"; "com3,System Access,MinimumPasswordAge,1" were inserted

Comment: Examples of rows not added are "com1,Event Audit,AuditSystemEvents,0" and "com2,Kerberos Policy,MaxTicketAge,10" and "
com3,System Access,NewAdministratorName,"Administrator""

Comment: @LamakDaruwala what errors were generated? kindly check if the `ID` is set as the primary key of the table. as you can see, the `ID` of the records that were not inserted already exists on the table.

Comment: Yes "ID" is the primary key. No errors are generated except that when i execute the query the following message is generated "3 rows affected by the last command, no resultset returned."

Comment: @LamakDaruwala since they are primary key. The value of ID is unique. Inserting value of the `ID` that already exists will fail.

Comment: @LamakDaruwala I just updated the answer. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: Hi sir, thank you very much for reminding me about that. Thanks alot!

Comment: I have unset ID as the primary key. Thanks alot!

Comment: Yes it does :D
Thanks a bunch sir!